# JList is getting bad while auto scrolling and auto selecting (GUI issue)

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, scroll, jlist

I've created a log for checking proxys.

This log shows me, which proxy is already in use (by selecting item). And the problem is that when log is auto scrolling, and auto selecting, im getting GUI issues like this (sometimes worst, sometimes better):

[image]

In addition, GUI modifications (adding items) are doing from other thread.

Anyone could tell me how to prevent it? The code is:

```java
class Log extends JScrollPane {
    private JList lista;
    private DefaultListModel modelListy;
    boolean selScroll;

    Log(String opis, boolean selScroll) { 
        super();
        modelListy = new DefaultListModel();
        lista = new JList(modelListy);
        setViewportView(lista);
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(opis));
        this.selScroll = selScroll;
        setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        Font displayFont = new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 10);
        lista.setFont(displayFont);
    }

    void clear() { 
        modelListy.clear();
    }

    void addItem(Object obj) { 
        modelListy.addElement(obj);
        if(!selScroll) {
            lista.ensureIndexIsVisible(modelListy.size()-1);
        }
    }

    void selectItem(int i) {
        lista.setSelectedIndex(i);
        if(selScroll) {
            lista.ensureIndexIsVisible(i+1);
        }
    }

    String getSelectedItem() {
        return (String)lista.getSelectedValue();
    }

    int itemCount() {
        return modelListy.size()-1;
    }

    int getSelectedIndex() {
        return lista.getSelectedIndex();
    }
}
```

Comment: I've seen this same problem with `JTree`

Comment: Was there any fix for this problem? :|

Comment: I didn't try fixing it as it didn't happen that often, but it confused me why it would be drawing the label outside of the list/tree.

Comment: Tomorrow i will try to remove border and post results here, probably it is the cause of this problem.

Comment: I believe it's somehow related to threading as your list and my tree were both multithreaded, so it's possible that we are both doing something wrong/not-quite-right.

Comment: Swing GUI objects should be constructed and manuipulated _only_ on the [event dispatch thread](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html). Violations can produce such artifacts intermittently.

Answer (score 2):

Try to call all the `lista.ensureIndexIsVisible(...);` inside `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`. It's possible that model updating wasn't finished when repaint is called.

Comment: Oh, thank you. Now its much better, but... sometimes content of window totally disappear, especially when adding many items at once to one Log. Do you know what could be a cause?

Comment: +1 This is the first time I see `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` is useful :)